# d3 v.4+ x-axis tick labels are incorrectly positioned upon transition

Tags: d3.js, svg, dimple.js

Trying to debug an issue when switching from 3.x series of d3 to the modular 4.x+ version. I am developing with dimple.js which builds upon d3.

The problem occurs when redrawing a graph via a transition, **x-axis tick labels are misplaced**. This does not occur using the older versions. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0jbk9f62/) with old, correct behavior. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bp2uc3za/1/) with new, incorrect behavior.

The problem appears to be the 3rd parameter to `rotate`: the correct labels have a non-zero value like

```
transform="rotate(90,0,231.90625) translate(-5, 0)"
```

while the misplaced labels have 0 for the 3rd parameter.

```
transform="rotate(90,0,0) translate(-5, 0)"
```

A few notes I've discovered while trying to debug:

- Labels are only misplaced when using a d3 transition. Dimple normally uses
  `ease-cubic-in-out` but if the developer specifies 0 milliseconds in `draw()`, the transition is skipped entirely, and the labels always show up correctly.
- Dimple populates the rotate values by calling `getBBox()` on `text` elements and using the resulting height: see line 300 of [dimple 2.2 draw()](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/2.2.0/src/objects/chart/methods/draw.js) and line
  301 of [dimple 2.3 draw()](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/blob/2.3.0/src/objects/chart/methods/draw.js). When using the new version, that bounding box is empty on elements which will be incorrectly positioned: `SVGRect {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0}`
- I attempted to identify the differences in the  elements when
  they are created, not sure if this is the source of the difference
  but I was unsuccessful anyway. (I believe it occurs in the functions
  at: line 8983 in `https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/v3.5.17/d3.js` and at
  line 47 in `https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/src/axis.js`
- Just to reiterate, with dimple 2.2 and below, which rely on d3 3.x,
  the label transitions work fine. It's only when upgrading to dimple
  2.3 and d3 4+, that the incorrect behavior shows up. Obviously there could be a difference in dimple but after walking through the
  code (virtually identical between dimple versions) I believe it is d3
  that introduces the breaking change.

Comment: the problem is how dimple positions text, it should rotate first without point of rotation and then translate to the correct location. `translate(0,68) rotate(90)` then no need to get the BBox

Comment: @rioV8 As I wrote, dimple does just fine in v.2.2 which interacts with D3 v.3. It also positions the text correctly in the latest version, if the developer skips the 'ease' transition. So I don't think there is any inherent flaw in dimple's methodology.